# error using R's htmltab: Error in `*tmp*`[[index]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, finance, google-finance

Trying to download INX from Google Finance using

```
x <- htmltab(doc = "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXSP%3A.INX&ei=Qu-TWOn-AtW1mQGQ06WYCQ")
```

and it gives this error:

```
Error in `*tmp*`[[index]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Where's your code?  See [ask]

Comment: what's `htmltab` ; which library is it from?

Comment: It's from the htmltab package in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get `htmltab` to work, but you can parse the web page using `library(rvest)`, and specifying the particular `xpath` of the table

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXSP%3A.INX&ei=Qu-TWOn-AtW1mQGQ06WYCQ"

read_html(url) %>%
    html_node(xpath = "//*[@class='gf-table historical_price']") %>%
    html_table()

#            Date     Open     High      Low    Close        Volume
# 1   Feb 2, 2017 2,276.69 2,283.97 2,271.65 2,280.85 2,321,960,100
# 2   Feb 1, 2017 2,285.59 2,289.14 2,272.44 2,279.55 2,478,979,663
# 3  Jan 31, 2017 2,274.02 2,279.09 2,267.21 2,278.87 2,555,320,206
# 4  Jan 30, 2017 2,286.01 2,286.01 2,268.04 2,280.90 2,108,083,825
# ...
```